# Why am i getting permission denied in firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, angularfire

I am using angularfire and doing a bulk update in the realtime database

instead of writing the complete path to the specified object I write the parents and the data I pass contains the rest of the path

for example let's say I have a path like `root/$date/$uid/myObject`

I specify in the rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "root" : {
      "$date" : {
        "$uid": {
          ".read": true,
          ".write" : "auth.uid === $uid && $date.matches(/someregex/)"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

and in angularfire I do the following

```
const data = {
 "12-03-2020": {
   "my-user-id": {
      data: "hello world!"
   }
 }
 "12-04-1236": {
   "my-user-id": {
      data: "hello world!"
   }
 },
 "12-06-1960": {
   "my-user-id": null
 },
}

this.db.object('root').update(data).then(...)
```

when writing the full path in the rule tester everything works fine but when trying it on my app i get `Permission Denied` also the method is working when setting write to `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update statement is executed as essentially a list of set statements of each **top-level** key in the update object. This means that your code is trying to write to `root/12-03-2020`, `root/12-04-1236` and `root/12-06-1960` and doesn't have write permission there.

It **is** possible to perform deep updates of specific properties, but you will have to specify the paths to the properties in the key. So the JSON in your question would fold into this structure to perform deep updates of (only) those specific values:

```
const data = {
 "12-03-2020/my-user-id/data": "hello world!",
 "12-04-1236/my-user-id/data": "hello world!"
 "12-06-1960/my-user-id": null
}
...
```

Comment: oops I went too fast still doesn't work on my angular app. only on the testing space

Comment: The problem I signaled is unrelated to Angular/AngularFire as far as I can tell. If you're still having problems after fixing this, it'd be helpful to see a minimal repro on a site like jsbin.

Comment: not sure what to put on a jsbin. what exactly happened is that on the testing interface of friebase i've written a JSON object with the path added the conditions and it worked. now when doing the same thing on typescript the rules don't work anymore and get permission denied. What would you like to see exactly. Shall I make an edit of the post? Many thanks in advance...

Comment: I'd like to see the minimal complete code that reproduces the problem. It that requires the regex in your rules, include the regex. If you can reproduce it without the regex, remove it. Same for the JSON: make sure it's the minimum, but complete, that is needed to reproduce the problem. Also include the actual UID, and verify that it's set by `console.log`ing right before you write to the database.

Comment: I think I foound the problem but still I'll do what you ask if that's not the one causing this. Thanks :)